Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love LEGO® Answers, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

What is the centre hole for in modern train tracks?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


What are LEGO baseplates made from?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Buying Individual MiniFigures

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Getting started with Mindstorms and/or Technic

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Which was the first set / minifig with two faces to choose from?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Invert motor block in EV3

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


identification of lego set by color and shape of inner box

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)


How can I order an Ev3 gyro in Europe

Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)


Advanced coloured lines following robot

Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)


How can I find the analog output of a color sensor?

Net Score: -4 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 4)

